# Give specific user permission to kill other users with logind?

Tags: permissions, logind, loginctl

Is it possible to give one user (the "main user") the permission to kill other users using logind/loginctl?

Comment: Have you tried setting the setuid permission bit to the command used to kill other users in order to be run as the root user? I haven't used systemctl but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the line bellow in the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
main_user ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/loginctl kill-user *
```